# 4-D visualization and projection

Tags: algebraic-topology, projection

We can divide $S^2$ in 2n triangles by considering the triangles that come from dividing the sphere with n meridians and the equator. I am trying to visualize a similar thing with $S^3$ and tetrahedra. I think that, as the triangles of $S^2$ share an edge, the tetrahedra of $S^3$ should share a face.

My aim is to visualize the 1-skeleton of such an object, but it seems I am 4-D blind...

Is there a way to visualize the projection of such an object in 3-D?

More generally: are there techniques to visualize 4-D object and project them in 3-D?

Comment: You can think of $S^3$ as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  So given a tessellation of the unit sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ by triangles (this is analogous to dividing the equator into $n$ pieces in one lower dimension), you get a division of $S^3$ into tetrahedra given by $\{0\}$ together with three vertices of a triangle on the sphere, and $\{\infty\}$ together with three vertices of a triangle on the sphere.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Stereographic Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#:~:text=In%20geometry%2C%20the%20stereographic%20projection,mapping%20is%20smooth%20and%20bijective.)

Comment: @JHF So I have 6 points on the sphere, three of them joined with the origin and among them, and the other three joined with $\infty$ and among them. Is it correct?

Comment: No, just as for $S^2$ every line segment between two consecutive points on the equator is joined with both the north and south poles, for $S^3$ you'd want to join every triangle on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to both $\{0\}$ and $\{\infty\}$ (which, as Kevin points out, is the analogue of north and south poles under stereographic projection).